# Is this query are ok? (multiple JOIN's in SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a query:

```
SELECT matches.id, 
matches.player1, 
matches.player2, 
users.firstname as firstname, 
tournaments.tid as tid, 
users.tempsalt as salt 
FROM matches 
INNER JOIN tournaments 
ON matches.tid = tournaments.tid 
INNER JOIN users 
ON matches.uid = users.uid 
WHERE ((matches.status = 0) 
OR (matches.status = 1)) 
AND (tournaments.status <> 3) 
AND (users.tempsalt = '324234324234')
```

Three tables - *matches*, *tournaments*, *users*

- **matches**(id, tid, uid, player1, player2, status)
- **users**(id, uid, firstname, tempsalt)
- **tournaments**(id, tid, status)

**Added:**
matches[1,3,2,John,Mark,0]
[2,3,NULL,Piter,Sara,1]

users[1,3,Alex,346]
[2,4,Sam,32423]

tournaments[1,3,2]
I wanna get in result:
[1,John,Mark,Sam,3,32423] and with NULL too [2,Piter,Sara,NULL,3,NULL]

If matches.uid is NULL then no results. But I want to get results when matches.uid is NULL too. Is is possible in one SQL query?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Use `left join` instead of `inner join`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `left join` and put the conditions of the joined tables in the `on` clause

```
SELECT m.id, m.player1, m.player2, 
       u.firstname as firstname, u.tempsalt as salt,
       t.tid as tid
FROM matches m
LEFT JOIN tournaments t ON m.tid = t.tid 
                       AND t.status <> 3
LEFT JOIN users u ON m.uid = u.uid 
                 AND u.tempsalt = '324234324234'
WHERE m.status in (0,1)
```